# Move the images to specific directory

Tags: php

```
    $fileType_array = array(IMAGETYPE_JPEG, IMAGETYPE_PNG);
$filenames = array($thumbnail_fieldname, $desktop_fieldname_1280x800, $desktop_fieldname_1366x768, $desktop_fieldname_1920x1080);
        $files = array();

        foreach($filenames as $filename){
            if(isset($_FILES[$filename]['tmp_name'])){
                $resource = getimagesize($_FILES[$filename]['tmp_name']);
                $type = $resource[2];
                if(in_array($type, $fileType_array, TRUE)){
                    echo "<p>Following files are images:";
                    array_push($files, $filename);
                    //$files[$filename] = $filename . "<br />"; 
                }

            }
```

This code gives me files that are images, what I would like to do is move those images to appropriate folders..for example for the thumbnail image the file is `thumbnail.png`, I would like to move this file to `images/thumbnails/thumbnail.png` folder..how can I do that? I think with `move_uploaded_file` but not sure how because of the constraint that if the specific file is not image leave it and move to the next one..for example the next one `desktop1280x800` file is not an image so it will skip and move to the next desktop file to move it to the directory if it is an image..so i cannot be done in order I guess..below is the code which moves those file I just want the specific one's to be moved not all

```
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$thumbnail_fieldname]['tmp_name'], $thumbnail_filename)
            //move desktop files
            && in_array(TRUE, array(
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$desktop_fieldname_1280x800]['tmp_name'], $desktop_filename_1280x800),
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$desktop_fieldname_1366x768]['tmp_name'], $desktop_filename_1366x768),
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$desktop_fieldname_1920x1080]['tmp_name'], $desktop_filename_1920x1080)))){
 //Files moved.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $type = $_FILES[$desktop_fieldname_1280x800]['type'];
 if(strpos($type, 'image') !== false)
 {
   //code
 }
```

Alternative

```
$filename_parts = explode('.', $_FILES[$desktop_fieldname_1280x800]['tmp_name']);
$ext = strtolower(end($filename_parts));
$autorized = array('png', 'jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'bmp' ); // ...
if(in_array($ext, $autorized))
{
 //code
}
```

Or a combination of both.

EDIT

```
  $fileType_array = array('image/jpeg', 'image/png');
  $filenames = array('test');
    $path_image = 'path/to/';
    foreach($filenames as $filename){
        if(isset($_FILES[$filename]['tmp_name'])){

            $type = $_FILES[$filename]['type'];
            if(in_array($type, $fileType_array)){
                 $name = $_FILES[$filename]["name"];
                 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$filename]['tmp_name'], $path_image.$name)){
                    echo 'File moved';
                 }
                 else
                 {
                    echo 'Error';
                 }
            }
            else
            {
                echo 'File is not an image or format is not accepted';
            }

        }
  }
 ?>
    <form method='POST' action='index.php' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
     <input type='file' name='test' />
     <input type='submit' value='go' />
     </form>
```

Comment: I think that is what my code does..checks if files are images.

Comment: What is in  $fileType_array ?

Comment: didn't get what you mean.

Comment: yeah no nvm didn't see you were using getimagesize() to get the type. So everyting works ?

Comment: nope, I want to use the ones that are images and move them to appropriate folders and store the paths in database..the code below is just temporary which I'm using for moving the files not just images..

Comment: here you go whole script so you can test